# How to send API requests to a server via JSON? Keep getting CORS errors

Tags: reactjs, api, nginx, centos, cors

I'm using ReactJs and Axios to send API requests to my server but I keep getting the same error:

`Failed to load http://***: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`

I'm trying to perform a POST request. I've also tried to download a Chrome Plugin to allow CORS. It did work for the GET requests, but not working for POST it looks like.

If I try to make requests to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users it's working fine. So I guess there's something wrong with the server.

My server is using Nginx and is on a CentOS 7 OS.

**Q:** How is it possible to enable CORS just for my local development (localhost) or specific websites?

**EDIT:** I have already tried using this config on my Nginx server - without luck: https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't answer you with some specific code, here's what happens (at least what happened last time I tried Angular and had similar issues):

Before sending any further requests, there'll be a header only `OPTIONS` HTTP request sent to the server URL. When answering this call, the server is supposed to send a header field `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` containing a whitelist of domains allowed to do further calls using the API. To whitelist all requests in your dev environment it should be enough to set Nginx to answer with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Answer (score 1):

For development I use the Firefox extension *CORS Everywhere*. It modifies all web traffic, to include the correct CORS headers. (It works at least with the somewhat dated Firefox in Opensuse 42.3.)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/

Note, that this subverts a security mechanism of the browser.

For deployment you must configure the server, to send the correct CORS headers. (I did never do this, the finished website is planned to work in a single IP.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server and the server is using Nodejs, this should work for you:

CD into your server folder:

```
cd server-folder
```

Then run this command in order to install the 'cors' package:

```
npm install cors
```

In order to access this package, go into your server file in your IDE and in the next available line:

```
const cors = require('cors');
```

Next, add this line to use the middleware (assuming you are using Express):

```
app.use(cors());
```